# How can I restrict permissions on a Sharepoint Online view?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online

This is a question about Sharepoint Online. I have a form collecting information which, with the help of Power Automate, is pushed to a Sharepoint list and we have a number of different users accessing it who are meant to be editing different fields. I would like to achieve the following:

- some fields of the list should be read-only (I believe this can be done in PowerShell);
- different users should have access to different fields, but some fields should be read-only for one user and editable for others.

So if the list has fields A, B, C and D and we have users Paul and Mary:

- A should be read-only for both of them;
- B and C should be visible but read-only to Paul and visible but editable to Mary;
- D should be hidden from Paul, but visible and editable (or read-only) to Mary.

Is there anyway to achieve this? Essentially, we are after something like views but restricted to a user subset with editing restrictions and them not been able to click anywhere to get the full item.

Regards,
George

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but you can grant such privileges only if you are the owner. I made almost the same thing before by going to the person responsible for department site and made myself an owner, then I specified which users can edit or not

Comment: I am the owner, but I am not looking at the whole list, I am looking essentially at field-level restrictions, would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. As per my knowledge, in SharePoint Online, there is no OOB way to set specific view-level permission.

Comment: No OOB is not a problem, happy to code something if high-level directions can be provided as to what to look for, how would you go about doing it? If that was an on-prem installation, would it have been possible (mainly interested in modern view, but if it is only possible in classic view please provide some pointers).